# How to parse the values from my array into my Googl pi chart

Tags: php, arrays, charts, google-visualization

Untill now the code beneath worked when I know the amount of possibilities.

```
    function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Boys age'],
      ['1 year old',  <?php echo $one; ?>],
      ['2 year old',  <?php echo $two; ?>],
      ['3 year old',  <?php echo $three; ?>],
      ['4 year old',  <?php echo $four; ?>],
      ['5 year old',  <?php echo $five; ?>],
      ['6 year old',  <?php echo $six; ?>],
      ['7 year old',  <?php echo $seven; ?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: '<?php echo $total; ?> Boys age ', 
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      pieHole: 0.4
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('BoysAge'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

But now I've got an array containing the number of ages.
The line:

```
    print_r(array_count_values($boysAge));
```

Results into this output:

```
    Array ( [10] => 5 [7] => 12 [8] => 9 [0] => 1 [9] => 10 [12] => 2 [11] => 3 )
```

It there simple (but smart) way to parse the the array data into the chart data?

Kind regards,

Frans

Answer (score 0):

you could convert the result of --> `array_count_values($boysAge)` -- to JSON
then add each count as a row in the data table

see following snippet...

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Boys age');

  var ageCount = <?php echo json_encode(array_count_values($boysAge)); ?>

  for (var age in ageCount) {
    data.addRow([age, ageCount[age]]);
  }

  var options = {
    title: '<?php echo $total; ?> Boys age ',
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    pieHole: 0.4
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('BoysAge'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```